# Turning off error message caret in GCC 4.8

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning, gcc4.8

GCC 4.8 seems to have added Clang-like error message display, e.g. like this:

```
player.c:725:9: warning: variable ‘delta’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int delta, rdelta;
         ^
```

I guess some people find this useful, but I find it superfluous, and it makes every error message use three lines of screen-space instead of one, where more error messages could be displayed instead.

Is there any way to turn it off? I've been reading through the GCC documentation, but haven't found it yet, at least. In particular, is there a way to turn it off "by default", so that I don't have to specify some `-fno-error-caret` or similar option to everything I compile?

Comment: If you compile with a Makefile, shouldn't it not be a big deal? Or if you have a  terminal, can't you just hit up for the last compile command?

Comment: Sure, it's not an enormous deal, but if I never want it, it would be far more convenient not to have to specify a probably rather long option every time I switch projects or lose my bash history or anything.

Comment: The only way I can think of is disabling the feature when compiling it maybe?

Answer (score 2):

It seems I still had the GCC 4.7 documentation installed, so that's why I didn't find the `-fno-diagnostics-show-caret` option to turn it off.

However, that still doesn't answer the question of how to turn it off by default, so I'll keep this question unanswered for quite a while in case anyone has information on that.